# Debes seleccionar una versión., En IOS

Tags: ios

estoy subiendo una app en IOS, todos los requerimientos fueron realizados, pero hay un ultimo paso que en la plataforma developer apple me menciona que debo seleccionar una version, pero seleccione todo los campos y no encuentro lo que me piden.

[image: Espero su ayuda]

Answer (score 1):

En efecto tienes que seleccionar la compilación
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Comment: Pues sí, carnal, pero en dónde?

Answer (score 0):

- Si no has seleccionado un archivo de compilación, debes hacerlo en el apartado de Compilación dentro del AppStore.
- Introduce también un número de versión en el apartado correspondiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que seleccionar la compilación, la cual puedes subirlo por XCode, una vez asociado el identificador de Mac.